# IBM Worklight: Push Notification Error on Android device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded the sample application for Push Notification Module, and tried to run it on a Samsung Tab 2. I discovered that it requires senderId and Key so I created these values using Google's GCM Console. Then, I ran app and it was successful. I then subscribed through the sample app and pressed on the Login button. After Login my LogCat shows the following:

> 03-14 13:03:10.648: V/GCMRegistrar(9351): Saving regId on app version
>   1 03-14 13:03:10.648: D/WLDroidGap(9351): Registered at the GCM server
>   with registration id
>   APA91bEUF25J1woHwcfEhG-73XXUyRJw6ul26VF0GQJBJQ9gtgjg0QK5gQ9Nq2sAeHiOKCJGRlJJvZ_0CvibjwS_eg9IUkHKez9zVxbgCtPsWj85DuHv6JbzydQY182-HvkbfM45lGG8cF_ndknxnG8XpyaZnh55eQ
>
> 03-14 13:03:10.671: D/WLDroidGap(9351): Notifying javascript on
>   successful registration
>
> 03-14 13:03:10.679: D/PushApplication(9351): Push notification device
>   token has changed, updating server notification token id.
>
> 03-14 13:03:10.687: D/PushApplication(9351): Request
>   [http://192.168.1.206:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/android/notifications]
>
> 03-14 13:03:10.710: D/PushApplication(9351): response
>   [http://192.168.1.206:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/android/notifications] success: /*-secure-
>
> 03-14 13:03:10.710: D/PushApplication(9351):
>   {"errors":[],"isSuccessful":true,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/
>
> 03-14 13:03:12.914: D/PushApplication(9351): Request
>   [http://192.168.1.206:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/android/notifications]
>
> 03-14 13:03:12.929: D/WLDroidGap(9351): Javascript script requests
>   dispatching to WL.Client.Push.__onmessage
>
> 03-14 13:03:52.625: D/PushApplication(9351): Request [login]
>
> 03-14 13:03:52.695: D/PushApplication(9351): Request
>   [http://192.168.1.206:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/android/notifications]
>
> 03-14 13:03:52.750: D/PushApplication(9351): response
>   [http://192.168.1.206:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/android/notifications] success: /*-secure-
>
> 03-14 13:03:52.750: D/PushApplication(9351):
>   {"isSuccessful":true,"WL-Authentication-Success":{"PushAppRealm":{"userId":"hello_13@gmail.com","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"hello_13@gmail.com"}}}*/

then after some time my Log cat shows:

> unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.Push$1@4128e920

and this error on web console:

> {"WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"device","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.impl.MobileClientData@e0d191"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"device"}},,"WL-Authentication-Failure":{"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"reason":"Login Failed"}}}*/

Next after login and subscribing it does not show anything that will allow me to know whether the notification was successfully pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow is wrong. You can't subscribe before logging it to the application. You first log in, and then you click on the subscribe button which should display a pop-up saying subscription was successful. You can then click on the isPushSupported and isSubscribed buttons to verify this.

Sending a notification afterwards should then succeed as well.

Google may on its own to unregister users that have not received push notifications for a while (it does not reveal after how long it has done that), perhaps that caused your issue. You did not specify clear enough reproduction steps.

Comment: from where i should Login??

Comment: What I am saying is that in the sample app, you're supposed to first see a login screen, and only then the buttons.

Comment: If you are talking about Gmail Login then i am  already Login through my account on the device. and from this account i created my sender key and id on Google api's. So when i run my app it did not ask about any login . It directly show me the page with 4 buttons

Comment: any help? i again run my project on device but it didn't ask any login.

Comment: Ok i solved my problem there was no "securityTest="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest" in application_descriptor.xml